# Combine 2 columns in 1, PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, gis, point

I have two columns column1, column2 that are curently type of real and I want to combine them in order to get a geometry(Point,4326).
My current code is this one:

```
INSERT INTO table2(location)
SELECT
    geometry(POINT(column1, column2))
FROM
    table1
```

I get this error: `Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)`

When I try to add the SRID in my geometry: `geometry(POINT(column1, column2),4326)` it doesnt recognize geometry, throwing error: `function geometry(point, integer) does not exist`

Note that location is type of `geometry(POINT, 4326)` . I have also tried UpdateGeometrySRID: `select UpdateGeometrySRID('public', 'table2', 'location', 4326) ;` but i still get the same errors in both cases.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
INSERT INTO table2(location)
SELECT
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(column1, column2), 4326);
FROM
    table1;
```

Comment: awesome, thank you! Had not notice the ST_SetSRID function in documendation!